# How to prevent a list from changing after being used as parameter in function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a little code which is not outputting the result as I wanted.

Code

```
def func_a(list1):
    list1.insert(2,'3')
    list1.append('c')
    return (list1)

def main():
    list_1 = ['1','2','a','b']    
    list_2 = func_a(list_1)
    print (list_1)
    print ("\n")
    print (list_2)

main()
```

Output to this code is:

```
['1', '2', '3', 'a', 'b', 'c']


['1', '2', '3', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

I want it to be:

```
['1', '2', 'a', 'b']


['1', '2', '3', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to create a copy of the list, and modify that:

```
def func_a(list1):
    list1copy = list1[:]
    list1copy.insert(2,'3')
    list1copy.append('c')
    return (list1copy)
```

You could also keep `func_a` the same, and just *call* it with a copy of the list:

```
list_2 = func_a(list_1[:])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a copy of the list to achieve what you want:

```
list_2 = func_a(list_1[:])
```

What happens here is that the list is passed to the function by reference, i.e. its content is present in memory only once. Inside the function, you change this original list and return the reference to it. Back at the calling place, you assign the same reference to another variable name, but still, there is only one list that has been altered by now.

Answer (score 0):

One should note that making a *shallow* copy as suggested (either in the function *func_a* or in the call to *func_a*) only prevents changes to the top level list, but not to components of mutable list elements:

```
def func_a(list1):
    list1.append("dada")
    list1[0]['a']=333
    return list1

def main():
    list_1 = [{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c':3}]
    list_2 = func_a(list_1[:])
    print(list_1)
    print("\n")
    print(list_2)
main()

[{'a': 333}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}]


[{'a': 333}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, 'dada']
```

Here the first element of list_1 was changed from {'a':1} to {'a':333}. To completely prevent changes to list_1 one can make a *deep* copy as shown below:

```
import copy
def func_a(list1):
    list1.append("dada")
    list1[0]['a']=333
    return list1

def main():
    list_1 = [{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c':3}]
    list_2 = func_a(copy.deepcopy(list_1))
    print(list_1)
    print("\n")
    print(list_2)
main()

[{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}]


[{'a': 333}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, 'dada']
```