# The python code isn't showing desired output , where is the problem?

Tags: python

My python code is :

```
new_alien={'color':'green','points':5,'speed':'slow'}
aliens=[]
for alien_number in range(10):
    aliens.append(new_alien)
print(f"total aliens:{len(aliens)}")
print(".......")
print(aliens)

for alien in aliens[:3]:
    if alien['color']=='green':
        alien['color']='yellow'
        alien['points']=10
        alien['speed']='fast'

print(aliens)
```

And it is showing output like:

```
total aliens:10
.......
[{'color': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}, {'color': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}, {'color': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}, {'color': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}, {'color': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}, {'color': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}, {'color': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}, {'color': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}, {'color': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}, {'color': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}]
[{'color': 'yellow', 'points': 10, 'speed': 'fast'}, {'color': 'yellow', 'points': 10, 'speed': 'fast'}, {'color': 'yellow', 'points': 10, 'speed': 'fast'}, {'color': 'yellow', 'points': 10, 'speed': 'fast'}, {'color': 'yellow', 'points': 10, 'speed': 'fast'}, {'color': 'yellow', 'points': 10, 'speed': 'fast'}, {'color': 'yellow', 'points': 10, 'speed': 'fast'}, {'color': 'yellow', 'points': 10, 'speed': 'fast'}, {'color': 'yellow', 'points': 10, 'speed': 'fast'}, {'color': 'yellow', 'points': 10, 'speed': 'fast'}]
```

Why is it changing all the elements of the list 'alien' though I looped through only the first 3 elements?

Comment: Because all the elements in aliens point to same alien.

Comment: Note how many dictionaries are created in total in this code. Only one is created at the very beginning.

Comment: Similar question [How to prevent a list from changing after being used as parameter in function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582810/how-to-prevent-a-list-from-changing-after-being-used-as-parameter-in-function)

Answer (score 2):

To properly copy dictionaries, you must use the `your_dictionary.copy()` method, as shown below:

```py
first_dict = {"world":"hello"}
second_dict = first_dict.copy()
second_dict["world"] = "goodbye"    # After doing this, first_dict is still {"world":"hello"}.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because all the elements in `aliens` refer to the same variable `new_alien`

Use `new_alien.copy()`

```
new_alien={'color':'green','points':5,'speed':'slow'}
aliens=[]
for alien_number in range(10):
    aliens.append(new_alien.copy())
    
    
print(f"total aliens:{len(aliens)}")
print(".......")
print(aliens)

for alien in aliens[:3]:
    if alien['color']=='green':
        alien['color']='yellow'
        alien['points']=10
        alien['speed']='fast'

print(aliens)
```

Comment: Thank you. Does this work similarly with lists too?

Answer (score 2):

A tricky one.

When a dictionary is stored in memory, and unlike a string, any variable pointing it will be the same dictionary. Try this:

```
a = {"foo": "bar"}
b = a
a["foo"] = "surprise!"
print(b)
```

You must use the .copy method of the dict to have diferent aliens:

```
alien.append(new_alien.copy())
```

Comment: Yes, the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve by moving the alien definition into the for loop. This will create a new dict in each array entry, rather than all referencing the same thing:

```
aliens=[]
for alien_number in range(10):
    aliens.append({'color':'green','points':5,'speed':'slow'})
print(f"total aliens:{len(aliens)}")
print(".......")
print(aliens)
```